# Below code is working fine with chrome but same code is not working with internet explorer. how to use speechsynthesis in internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, html, speech-synthesis

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
   </head>

   <body onload="myFunction()">
      <script>
             function myFunction() {

               // Create the utterance object setting the chosen parameters
               var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();

               var myarray = new Array(4);

               myarray[0] =  "Move Bay from door 10 to 20";               
               utterance.text = myarray[0];
                utterance.lang = "ar-uk";
               speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);  
             }              
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

passing the text to speech synthesis property text and try to convert text to speech

Comment: According to https://caniuse.com/#feat=speech-synthesis it is only supported in Edge, and not supported by Internet Explorer at all.

Answer (score 1):

Look here: [SpeechSynthesisUtterance Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance)

It's not supported by IE.

Comment: Maybe have a look at @Mohammed mentioned WSR

Answer (score 0):

it is not supported Microsoft has the free SAPI (Speech API) which uses WSR, Windows Speech Recognition'

Comment: If you have any example using WSR .. can you please share the link?

Comment: Check this website it has some good examples https://davidwalsh.name/speech-recognition

Comment: It's not supported by IE...if you having any working code which support in IE (text to speech)... can you share please .